# Exceptions and IDispatchMessageInspector

Tags: wcf, logging, exception

I'm using IDispatchMessageInspector to inspect request/response messages in my WCF service and log some data to our logging database. I also have a custom error handler which catches exceptions and transforms them to faults. I'd like to be able to log the exception (if any) in the IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply() method but I cannot figure out how to capture exception data. Is there a fault collection of some sort that I should be looking for? I realize I could log the exception in the IErrorHandler.HandleError() method, but I'd like to include the exception details along with the other details that I'm capturing while inspecting the request/response messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [something I wrote](http://winterdom.com/2006/10/idispatchmessageinspectorfaultsandonewayoperations) a while ago about this topic. Basically, an exception will cause a [fault message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.isfault.aspx) to be sent to the client as a reply